# Two directories point to the same location

Tags: linux

I have two locations that point to the same physical space:

```
$ df -h /home/admindev
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1      1008G  810G  153G  85% /data2

$ df -h /data2
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1      1008G  810G  153G  85% /data2
```

Though, I only find /data2 in the results of this command:

```
$ df
/dev/sdd1      1056762036 848526448 159901448  85% /data2
```

How is defined /home/admindev?

Mark

Comment: check for softlinks `ls -ld /home/admindev` and `ls -ld /home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df $some_file` display the filesystem on which `$some_file` is. From your commands, there is a filesystem mounted as `/data2`. Since the path to `/home/admindev` is not a child of `/data2`, something is "forwarding" `/home/admindev` to `/data2`. This can be either:

- A soft link (obtained with `ln -s`)
- A "bind mount" (obtained with `mount --bind ...`)

Either can be on `/home` or on `/home/admindev`. The soft link can be checked using ls, the bind-mount appears in the output of `mount`.

Comment: Thank you, I could see the link between /home/admindev and /data2 with readlink.